# Redirect the title field of a content type to some external url in a view

Tags: nodes, redirection

I am using drupal 7 with view3

I have content type named **News** having many fields along with a taxonomy field named **News Type**, News type have terms: '**Free**' and '**Premium**', I am displaying News on my page through view, the problem i am facing is I need to redirect the news node to some external url like popup, if its premium news, means if its **News Type** field is set to **premium** it should not be **redirected** to its content, In short when premium news is viewed it should popup some message instead of showing the content of that news,and for free news it should go to the news node detail page. Please find the screenshot of view attached. Please help will be greatly appreciated. If I need to clarify please comment.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To change content link... You can try using [Views Conditional](https://drupal.org/project/views_conditional) Module...

Project page says

> Views Conditional is a simple module that allows you to define
>   conditionals (if xxx then yyy) with fields in views. Conditions
>   include:
>
> Equal To
>
> Not Equal To
>
> Greater Than
>
> Less Than
>
> Empty
>
> Not Empty
>
> Views conditional allows you to output text based on the result of the
>   condition.

If it doesn't work then you can solve it using [views php](https://drupal.org/project/views_php) module..

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I do not understand how views conditional module will help me, I need to change the href of a title of news to popup if its taxonomy is premium.

Comment: For Field Term name check for premium.. Rewrite results of term name and display a link using Replacement patterns... Create one more term field just to display term name... Disable content link and use above as content link.. Make sure Term name field is below other fields while using replacement patterns and exclude unnecessary fields..

Comment: "For Field Term name check for premium", You mean I will add term name as a field, but it will be itself added as a link to term view page, how I can override its link with using replacement pattern. Also I need to show the title field of a news, because free news should be viewed by users, please clarify me if I am wrong.